# Getting rid of a for loop in R

Tags: r

I would like to sample a given vector with different sets of probabilities without a loop. Is there a way to do this?

For example in this code I would like to replace the loop with some sort of apply() structure or anything really ..

```
a <- c(1,2,3)
p <- matrix(c(.1,.1,.8,.1,.8,.1,.8,.1,.1), nrow=3)
s <- matrix(ncol=5, nrow=3)
for(i in 1:nrow(p)){
s[i,] <- sample(a, size=5, replace=T, prob=p[i,])
}
```

thanks for the help!

Comment: Note that `apply` is still using a loop (as opposed to using a vector approach), but does often result in more readable code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`apply` on `p` itself:

```
t(apply(p, 1, sample, x=a, size=5, replace=TRUE))
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    3    3    1    3    3
[2,]    2    2    1    1    2
[3,]    1    1    1    1    1
```

**Edit** I had a `functional::Curry` in here, until flodel pointed out that it wasn't necessary, as `apply` gives an automatic curry by allowing named arguments via `...`.